# C++ Can I return iterator on a local vector from a method?

Tags: c++, vector, reference, iterator

I have this method:

```
route_departure_const_iterator departure_at(platform_route_const_reference pr, packed_time tm)
{
    std::vector<route_departure_object> v;
    for (auto&& e : pr.departures) {
        int i = 0;
        while (true)
        {
            if (pr.tt->timetable_route_departures.at(i).platform_name == pr.platform_name && pr.tt->timetable_route_departures.at(i).route_name == pr.route_name && pr.tt->timetable_route_departures.at(i).departure_time >= e)
            {
                route_departure_const_reference rd = pr.tt->timetable_route_departures.at(i);
                v.push_back(rd);
                break;
            }
            i++;
        }
    }
    return v.begin();
}
```

My question is, if I initialized new vector of objects in this method, when I return the iterator, will it point at this vector or will this vector be deleted after exiting the method?
Then, pr.tt->timetable_route_departures is vector of route_departure_object like vector v.
route_departure_const_reference rd is a reference to route_departure_object. Will my vector v consists of the original objects by references or they will be references on new objects?

With this method, when I will use the returned iterator outside this method, on vector of references to the same objects, will it work?

I mean, I have this method:

```
route_departures_const_reference departures(platform_route_const_reference pr)
{
    std::vector<route_departure_object> v;
    for (auto&& e : pr.departures) {
        int i = 0;
        while (true)
        {
            if (pr.tt->timetable_route_departures.at(i).platform_name == pr.platform_name && pr.tt->timetable_route_departures.at(i).route_name == pr.route_name && pr.tt->timetable_route_departures.at(i).departure_time == e)
            {
                route_departure_const_reference rd = pr.tt->timetable_route_departures.at(i);
                v.push_back(rd);
                break;
            }
            i++;
        }
    }
    return v;
}
```

There are many more objects in pr.tt->timetable_route_departures, I just choose some of them. Then, when I will use returned iterator on this returned vector, will it point at the exact same chosen objects in pr.tt->timetable_route_departures?????
Thanks a lot for help!

Comment: No, the iterator will no longer be valid if the corresponding container instance ceases to exist at the end ot that functions scope.

Comment: Is there a way I can return a valid iterator?

Comment: You can return the whole container, usually RVO would prevent a copy is made, but rather a move takes place. Or work with ranges as the c++ standard algorithms do.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ but the returned vector will be a valid reference, no?

Comment: No it will be a moved instance. There isn't anything to reference any longer after the function returned.

Answer (score 4):

> if I initialized new vector of objects in this method, when I return the iterator, will it point at this vector or will this vector be deleted after exiting the method?

The vector will be destroyed when it goes out of scope when the function exits, thus the returned iterator will be left dangling.

> Will my vector v consists of the original objects by references or they will be references on new objects?

It will contain *copies* of the original objects.

> when I will use the returned iterator outside this method, on vector of references to the same objects, will it work?

No.  Because one, you don't have a vector of references, but a vector of copied objects.  And two, the vector was already destroyed and you have a dangling iterator.

> `route_departures_const_reference departures(platform_route_const_reference pr)`

If `route_departures_const_reference` is actually a reference (ie, `std::vector<route_departure_object>&`) as its name suggests, then you would be returning a dangling reference to a destroyed vector.

> when I will use returned iterator on this returned vector, will it point at the exact same chosen objects in pr.tt->timetable_route_departures?????

No, it would be referring to the *copied* objects that were made (if the returned vector/iterator were valid to begin with).

Comment: How can I return valid vector reference from the second method then? And iterator in the first method.

Comment: @Rikib161999 Returns the objects you want by value in both cases instead of iterators or references.

Comment: I have to return reference to container and iterator reference

Comment: @Rikib161999 Like πάνταῥεῖ said in another comment, in the second method you would have to return the actual vector itself **by value**, not **by reference**. Let the compiler copy/move the vector as needed.  In the first method, the only way to return just an iterator is if the vector is stored somewhere else outside of the function so it survives past the function exit. "*I have to return reference to container and iterator reference*" - well, then, your requirement is unrealistic and needs to change

Comment: so it will be a reference to new vector which has the same data as original objects, it is enough for me like this. But with iterator, I need the reference

Comment: @Rikib161999 This seems like an unlikely requirement. Maybe you actually want a `std::vector<route_departure_object*> v;` to store pointers to the original object. Then, you could return a `route_departure_const_reference` to the original object.

Comment: you can return a pair <vector , unsigned int = (v.iterator - v.begin())>